# Select last message from conversation (one message between two users)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple chat app where I need to get last message of each conversation between two users (`user1` being you)

this is my table

```
| id | sender_id | receiver_id | message | timestamp |
```

this is my query but it returns last message of both users instead of last message between two users

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM chat WHERE (sender_id='user_id' OR receiver_id='user_id')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as m GROUP BY `sender_id`
```

So I only need last message between the two users not two messages

EDIT

I have multiple conversation stored in that table so I want it to pull last message from all conversations that the user is in.
So if I'm chatting with 3 people it should return 3 messages each message being the last of that conversation

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT chat.*
  FROM chat
  JOIN (  
         SELECT MAX(id) id
           FROM chat
          WHERE (sender_id='user_id' OR receiver_id='user_id')
       ) x ON chat.id = x.id
```

The subquery finds the largest chat.id value (meaning the latest message, presumably) matching your criterion. Then the join filters the chat table to show only that entry.

Or, even more simply, you can use a variant of your query. But this won't be as fast.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM chat 
 WHERE (sender_id='user_id' OR receiver_id='user_id')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This returns only one message between all conversations. I forgot to mention that the table stores multiple conversations so I want last message of each conversation. I edited my question